# Table form with two checkbox columns

Tags: 7, forms

I know it is fairly easy to create a table form with one column of checkboxes using table_select. But I would like to have two columns, preferably on the right of the text (as opposed to checkboxes in the left margin with table_select).

I looked at the code of the permissions table in core, but that one seems closely integrated with theming and I would like to avoid messing with that.

What would be the best way to achieve this? I'm using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not seem possible.

However, I found that with [tabledrag](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_tabledrag/7) I could do what I wanted. Instead of having two checkboxes, I used the dragging option instead of one and left the other checkbox in the row you can select by dragging upward. This had the added benefit of being able to specify  the order for the items.

The [simple table drag example](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/tabledrag_example!tabledrag_example_simple_form.inc/7) was easy enough to follow and implement.